# Trying to create a dynamic enough model to handle dynamic questions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, dynamic

I am trying to create a dynamic model for a set of questions that are pulled dynamically into my app.

I want to set my input types equal to a question id (which is unique). Then I want to associate those answers with a value field in my model.

I have this model:

```
public class QuestionViewModel
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        public string QuestionType { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }

        public List<QuestionOptionViewModel> Options { get; set; }
    }
    public class QuestionOptionViewModel
        {
            public int? Id { get; set; }

            public string Text { get; set; }

            public string StringValue { get; set; }
            public bool OptionValue {get; set;}

        }
```

So I tried to do a texboxfor like below. I was hoping that this would set the form name = "id" and then set the value to my model property StringValue. But it doesn't work.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Options.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <label for="@Model.Options[i].Text">@Model.Options[i].Text</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(o => Model.Options[i].StringValue, new { name = Model.Options[i].Id, @class = "form-control", placeholder = "" })
    </div>
}
```

Let me walk you through the model being given to me pseudo code style. It should explain what I want to do.

```
QuestionViewModel
   int = 1
   questionType = Text
   Text = What is your name?
QuestionOptionViewModel
   int = 1
   Text = FirstName
   StringValue = *I want to set the response here*
   OptionValue = *If it was a radio I want to store bool here*

   int = 2
   Text = LastName
   StringValue = *I want to set the response here*
   OptionValue = *If it was a radio I want to store bool here*
```

So I added into the model the StringValue part. I want to catch the responses there so I can dynamically have a trace that this questions input box would have the name of QuestionOption int. And store the value in StringValue (since text in this example).

I am confused on the appropriate way to do this in C# MVC? What would be the correct way to handle dynamically created questions that are pulled into a web page. I can easily pull them out using my model. But I am unsure the proper way to store them back into the model.

As requested here is a screen grab of a single question. [image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can you show a screen grab of a single question what you are expecting?

Comment: Posted the screen grab of a single question which as you see has to QuestionOptions (firstName and lastName). The text box fields are totally dynamic that is why I want to use ids as the input names.

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed because it's unclear what your problem is. The best I can tell you're just trying to figure out how save the responses to the questions? If that's the case, you would need a new entity, something like `QuestionOptionResponse`, with a foreign key to the `QuestionOption` and basically just the value that was posted. Don't store a foreign key to the actual `Question` because you can get to this from the `QuestionOption` relationship.